# nsoutlineview cell background changes color during animations on Yosemite

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview, osx-yosemite

I have an app that has been running well under OS X 10.7 through 10.9.  When it runs under 10.10, a visual problem appears that I am having trouble tracking down.

In essence, it appears that the cell background color changes during the animation of expanding and collapsing the outline. Here is a very brief (slo-mo) video showing the problem:

http://www.thirdstreetsoftware.com/downloads/Misc/paletteclip.mp4

The problem shows up only when run on OS X 10.10, regardless of whether it was built with Xcode 5 or 6, on 10.9 or 10.10.

Any idea where I should be looking for the problem?

Comment: Try the next release.

Answer (score 0):

Try to migrate to view-based table view, as cell-based table view is deprecated.